# Regex to Get SWF/Flash Value - VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, get, flash

I want to write "regex rule" to get/grab swf value from webpage

I could simply do "*.swf"

but we have two issues here :
we could get swf from param tag & embed tag

---

**UPDATE: 07/03/2016**

**How about getting all (*.swf) including values of param & embed?**

thank you

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Please post the specific patterns that you want to match.

Comment: I want to extract swf links from webPage so I used this regex
[a-zA-Z0-9\.\:\/]
but how to make it start from "http://" and end until "*.swf" ?

Comment: how about getting swf from param tag & tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
http://[a-zA-Z0-9\.:/]+?\.swf
```

**+** means "one or more times", and **?** means "reluctantly".  So for the middle part, it is grabbing any character that matches the [] criteria, but as soon as it finds **.swf**, the [] stops because it is reluctant, and lets the **\.swf** match instead.

There is one pitfall in this approach.  What if you have a link that begins with **http://** but does not end in **.swf**?  Then the [] criteria may continue matching past the end of the link, until the [] criteria fails, or until it reaches some **.swf**.  If you want to be super careful about this, you can put in a lookahead for the end of a link, and make that fail the regex.

Perhaps your HTML has all links ending with a double quote ".  Then you could use

```
http://[a-zA-Z0-9\.:/](?!")+?\.swf
```

to make the regex immediately fail upon reaching the end of a link without finding a **.swf**

Finally, you may need to escape all the slashes depending on your language.

Comment: how about getting swf from param tag & embed tag?

Comment: If my answer in 2014 answered your question, you should accept it as the correct answer.  If you want help, you need to take the time to explain yourself clearly.  You should write examples of something you *do* and something you *do not* want your regex to capture.